# Error on certain line: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: bash

Have an error "Syntax error: "(" unexpected" when execute an script:

`sync.sh: 11: sync.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

line 11 contains on this:

`declare -a FOLDERS=('/scripts' '/backup')`

and on the top of script have the interpreter:

`#!/bin/bash`

Execute the script with:

```
sh /wdmycloudex2/$(hostname)/scripts/sync.sh
/wdmycloudex2/RASPBIAN/scripts/sync.sh: 11: /wdmycloudex2/RASPBIAN/scripts/sync.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

The firsts 11 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP='10.0.1.7'
PORT='443'

HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
DATE=$(date +%d%m%Y_%H%M%S)
SOURCE='/scripts'
DEST='/wdmycloudex2'

declare -a FOLDERS=('/scripts' '/backup')
```

anybody know and explain what's the problem?

Comment: The line seems correct, could you please provide more info about the script?

Comment: How are you running your script, and what are the first 11 lines of the script? In other words, post a [mcve].

Comment: I update the post

Comment: Try running it with `bash`, not `sh`.

Comment: Or, for extra bizarro points, try running it with `perl`, not `sh`.

Comment: with bash the script is run correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The header `#!/bin/bash` is ignored when you start the script with `sh sync.sh`.
It will go better with `bash /wdmycloudex2/RASPBIAN/scripts/sync.sh` or

```
chmod +x /wdmycloudex2/RASPBIAN/scripts/sync.sh
/wdmycloudex2/RASPBIAN/scripts/sync.sh
```